# What are best practices when augmenting and building on the keys provided by someone else's package

Tags: expl3, xparse, key-value

The situation is one where I'm developing my own commands and environments which build on the commands and environments provided by another package: for ease of talking let's call this *other package* the **first module**.  The **first module** provides me with an environment for which parameters can be setting using key-values:

```
\begin{<first-module-env>}[<key-values>]
    .... various content .....
\end{<first-module-env>}
```

I would like to build on this environment and possibly supplement the earlier packages's range of permissible key-values.

If the **first modules** provided me with a command to directly process the keys, then things would be fairly straight-forward.  For example, if I were given something like,

```
\firstmodulekeysetter{<key-values>}
```

Then I could build something along the lines of

```
\keys_define:nn { acellett/augmentation } { ..... }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{acellett}{ O{} }
  {  \keys_set_known:nnN { acellett/augmentation } { #1 } \l_tmpa_clist
     \exp_args:NV \firstmodulekeysetter \l_tmpa_clist
     .... }
   { .... }
```

But the **first module** might not be so user friendly.  It might only allow me to access the keys through an optional argument to an environment.

Here's an example which shows how I'm trying to handle *augmenting* the allowable key-values of **first module**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% module "first_module"
\tl_new:N \l_first_module_a_tl
\tl_new:N \l_first_module_b_tl

\keys_define:nn { first/module/set }
  {
    a .code:n = { \tl_set:Nn \l_first_module_a_tl { #1 } },
    b .code:n = { \tl_set:Nn \l_first_module_b_tl { #1 } },
  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{firstenv}{ O{} }
  { 
    \par
    \keys_set:nn { first/module/set } { #1 }
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
    a & \l_first_module_a_tl \\
    b & \l_first_module_b_tl \\
  }
  {
    \end{tabular}\par
  }
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% module "augmented_module"
\tl_new:N \l_ae_augmented_module_x_tl
\tl_new:N \l_ae_augmented_module_y_tl

\keys_define:nn { ae/augmented/module/set }
  {
    x .code:n = { \tl_set:Nn \l_ae_augmented_module_x_tl { #1 } },
    y .code:n = { \tl_set:Nn \l_ae_augmented_module_y_tl { #1 } },
  }

\cs_new:Npn \__ae_augmented_calling_first:n #1 
  {
    \begin{firstenv}[#1]
  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{augmentedenv}{ O{} }
  {
    \keys_set_known:nnN { ae/augmented/module/set }{ #1 } \l_tmpa_clist
    \exp_args:NV \__ae_augmented_calling_first:n \l_tmpa_clist
    x & \l_ae_augmented_module_x_tl \\
    y & \l_ae_augmented_module_y_tl \\
  }
  {
    \end{firstenv}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

  \textbf{First Environment}
  \begin{firstenv}[a={A},b={is for Apple}]
  \end{firstenv}

  \textbf{Augmented Environment}
  \begin{augmentedenv}[a={B},b={is for Banana},x={X},y={is for Xylophone  }]

  \end{augmentedenv}

\end{document}
```

It's been mentioned before that using `\exp_args` is discouraged.
Is there a better way to do this?  Is it necessary for me to create the function `\__ae_augmented_calling_first` to allow me to pass the `\l_tmpa_clist`?

Comment: It mostly depends on what the augmented environment should do; this example doesn't seem very clear about what you have in mind. I don't see problems in the code; I would define a variant of `\__ae_augmented_calling_first:n` rather than using `\exp_args:NV` and avoid `\begin` and `\end`, preferring `\firstenv[#1]` and `\endfirstenv`.

Comment: @egreg Is there a reason to avoid `\begin` and `\end`, as you suggest?

Comment: Not adding a level of grouping.

Comment: Also, better error reporting if the environment is not closed correctly.

Comment: @bruno Any of you want to write an anaswer?

Comment: @egreg Any of you want to write an anaswer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd say that this is the right way for augmenting the set of options, even for changing the behavior of already existing keys (not in the example, but I think you get the idea).

I made some changes to the code, using the proper way of defining keys, as `.code:n` should be the last resort.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% module "first_module"

\keys_define:nn { first/module/set }
  {
    a .tl_set:N = \l_first_module_a_tl,
    b .tl_set:N = \l_first_module_b_tl,
  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{firstenv}{ O{} }
  { 
    \par
    \keys_set:nn { first/module/set } { #1 }
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
    a & \l_first_module_a_tl \\
    b & \l_first_module_b_tl \\
  }
  {
    \end{tabular}\par
  }
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% module "augmented_module"
\clist_new:N \l_ae_augmented_options_clist

\keys_define:nn { ae/augmented/module/set }
  {
    x .tl_set:N = \l_ae_augmented_module_x_tl,
    y .tl_set:N = \l_ae_augmented_module_y_tl,
  }

\cs_new:Npn \__ae_augmented_calling_first:n #1 
  {
    \firstenv[#1]
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__ae_augmented_calling_first:n { V }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{augmentedenv}{ O{} }
  {
    \keys_set_known:nnN { ae/augmented/module/set }{ #1 } \l_ae_augmented_options_clist
    \__ae_augmented_calling_first:V \l_ae_augmented_options_clist
    x & \l_ae_augmented_module_x_tl \\
    y & \l_ae_augmented_module_y_tl \\
  }
  {
    \endfirstenv
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

  \textbf{First Environment}
  \begin{firstenv}[a={A},b={is for Apple}]
  \end{firstenv}

  \textbf{Augmented Environment}
  \begin{augmentedenv}[a={B},b={is for Banana},x={X},y={is for Xylophone  }]

  \end{augmentedenv}

\end{document}
```

Note the variant definition of `\__ae_augmented_calling_first:V` that's preferable to using `\exp_args:NV` although the result is exactly the same: the name of the function expresses more clearly the nature of the argument that's expected.

Using `\firstenv` and `\endfirstenv` avoids a new level of grouping (and better error messages if `augmentedenv` is not properly closed.

[image]