# Is `.code:n` still a last resort when setting LaTeX3 keys and if so, why?

Tags: expl3

I am making headway with a `expl3` package I am writing, hence many questions on this subject, but I was reading an [answer by @egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223785/273733) to [What are best practices when augmenting and building on the keys provided by someone else's package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123318/273733) where @egreg states that

> `.code:n` should be the last resort

when setting `l3keys` key-values. Is this still true in 2023 (the question/answer was from 2013) and if so, why is this please? The [LaTeX3 interfaces documentation (p. 239)](https://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) doesn't explain the downsides, it just introduces it.

Comment: Of course, I don't know for sure, since I'm not such a pro like some others on this side. But I could imagine that `code:n` generally just has more code in its key definition part and thus its slower/less robust than the other more specific variants. But I might be wrong (and if so, would also be happy to know the real reason since I'm using `l3keys` regularly too)

Comment: much as it pains me to agree with egreg,  `.code` is just "arbitrary stuff" so you lose the self documenting nature, and in some cases inbuilt checking of the more specific forms.  ` a .tl_set:N = ...,` tells you that the key `a` takes a value and stores it in a local variable. `a.code:n ={....}` just tells you there is a key and something happens and you need to read ... to see exactly what.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So it's last resort as a way of defining a key rather than last resort as any way at all?

Comment: @cfr oh sure, it's the most general and powerful form, but probably if you use it to set (say) a boolean you'll forget some checking detail the built in one does and if you don't forget the added code will obscure what the key is doing so it's simpler to use a pre-existing key type if there is one

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if you wanted to post an answer I would happily accept to close this question, that makes sense that is too non-specific, I will try to avoid it. Just confused as to why it was `taboo` but now it makes sense, thank you

Comment: So is missing code documentation the only drawback of `code:n` (which would totally make sense)? Or can there be also some perfomance issues?

Comment: @lukeflo .code is basically a def so on its own it's got no performace issues. Whether the code you add to the `.code` to set a boolean key or any of the other types is as efficient as the code backing up the supplied key types depends on how that code compares with Joseph's....

Comment: @lukeflo I don't think it's just 'missing code documentation' if by that you mean that you might not document what the code does. In that case, there wouldn't be an issue provided you documented the code. I think the point is that you'd have to read either the code or the documentation of the code to get any idea what it did. That's in contrast with something like `.tl_set:N` which advertises what it does. You'd need to read more to know why the author had it do it (macro-level), but you know what it does (micro-level) immediately.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK thanks. Its good to know that there is no general drawback. Of course, if you write bad code, its bad code... :)

Comment: @cfr sorry, I meant it the way that you explained it. Maybe I would've better written 'traceability' instead of 'documentation'. I'm not native in English (you might have noticed ;) ), thus sometimes I tend to use the wrong term.

Comment: @lukeflo Oh, no problem. 'Documentation' just made me think 'manual'! Your English is excellent. Much better than my not-English-and-not-Welsh!

Comment: @cfr thank you. And finally I've learned something: to distinguish better between documentation written as manual and documentation in sense of tracing code context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much as it pains me to agree with egreg, `.code` is just "arbitrary stuff" so you lose the self documenting nature, and in some cases inbuilt checking of the more specific forms.

`a .tl_set:N = ...,` tells you that the key a takes a value and stores it in a local variable.

`a.code:n ={....}` just tells you there is a key and something happens and you need to read ... to see what exactly what.

It's the most general and powerful form, but probably if you use it to set (say) a boolean you'll forget some checking detail the built in one does and if you don't forget the added code will obscure what the key is doing so it's simpler to use a pre-existing key type if there is one.